# Major Issue with linking 2 views to view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am making a reflex test app, where one screen is the game, and if you press a button, you can segue into another screen, which contains a scoreboard as a table view. I initially attached the second view to a second `UIViewController` using cocoa touch, but the problem was, I couldn't access any of the variables or data in the first `UIViewController`, and that was essential (because the table has to reload its data from the first `UIViewController`). I then tried to make the second `UIViewController` a subclass of the first `UIViewController` ( and I was faced with problems), so I abandoned that idea. Now that both views are connected to one `UIViewController`, I am faced with multiple problems. First, when attempting to perform functions and change values of data which are not present in the screen (IE: reloading the table data on view did load, which leads to an error because the table wasn't present on the screen). Are there any solutions to this, and is there a way to connect all the data in one view controller to another? Thank  You.
Here is the code(it's in 1 `UIViewController`)

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
var arr = [Int]()
var timer = NSTimer()
var countdowntimer = NSTimer()
var count = 0
var countdown = Int(arc4random_uniform(4000) + 1000)
var highscore:Int!
var buttonTapCounter:Int!
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()


@IBOutlet weak var beginButton: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var resetDataButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var averageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bestLabel: UILabel!





@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var highScoreButton: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

func updateTime() {
    countdown = countdown - 1
    if countdown <= 0 {
        startButton.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        startButton.text = "Tap Now!"
        countdowntimer.invalidate()
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "red")
        count = 0
        Timer()
    }
}

func Timer() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target:self, selector:Selector("reflexTest"), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)

}

func reflexTest() {
    count = count + 1
    timerLabel.text = "\(count) ms"
}



@IBAction func returnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonTapCounter = 0
}


@IBAction func scoreButtonTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
    table.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func beginTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if startButton.text == "Tap when the Color Changes" {
        startButton.text = "You tapped too early!"
        countdowntimer.invalidate()
        countdown = Int(arc4random_uniform(4000) + 1000)
    } else {
        if count == 0 {
            countdowntimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            startButton.text = "Tap when the Color Changes"
            countdown = Int(arc4random_uniform(4000) + 1000)
            timerLabel.text = "\(count) ms"
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "green")
            startButton.text = "Tap to Begin"
            arr.append(count)
            count = 0
            highscore = minElement(arr)
            highScoreButton.text = "Best: \(highscore) ms"
            saveDefaults()
            loadDefaults()
        }

    }

}

func loadDefaults() {

    if let savedArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("data") as? [Int] {
    self.arr = savedArray
    }
}
func saveDefaults() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.arr, forKey: "data")

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"
    let dateInFormat = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = String(arr[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
func highScoreButtonText() {
    //highScoreButton.text = "Best: \(highscore) ms"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadDefaults()



        highscore = minElement(arr)
       highScoreButtonText()




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

The problematic code is in viewDidLoad, and whenever I reload the data. It is mainly because of the fact that there are 2 views. I know I should create 2 separate view controllers, but is there a way to link all data in between them? Thanks.
​

Answer (score 0):

Data that you need to share shouldn't be inside a view controller.  Create an object to act as a data model instead.

It can be a singleton, or can be owned by the app delegate...whatever way you like so that it can be accessed by the controllers that need it.

(You can even have the first controller own it an pass a reference to the second controller...but that doesn't scale very well as the app becomes bigger.)